# Div não englobando seus elementos

Tags: css, html5

```css
/*   Portal Aluno  */


#header-menu{
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border:0px;
 bottom: 800px;
 left: 10%;

}

#C-icon{
position:relative;
border:0px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
right: 71%; 
top: 7%;
}

#fb-icon{
position: relative;
border:0px;
margin-left:  50px;
padding: 0;
right: 80%;
top: 9%;
}

#ambiente-icon{
position: relative;
border:0px;
margin-right:100px; 
margin-left: 0;
padding: 0;
left: -15%;
bottom: 41%;

}

#youtube-icon{
 position: relative;
 border:0px;
 margin-right:  0;
 padding: 0;
 bottom: 41%;
 right: 20%;
}

#sair-icon{
 position: relative;
 border:0px;
 margin-left:0;
 padding: 0;
 bottom: 41%;
 left: 55%;
}

#header-icons li {
  border:0px; 
  list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 137px;
 left: 130px;
}

 
/*#header-icons li{
 display: inline-block;
}*/
@keyframes space01 {
  /* line 163, ../scss/main.scss */
  0% {
    bottom:  720px;
  }

  /* line 166, ../scss/main.scss */
  50% {
    bottom: 751px;
  }

  /* line 169, ../scss/main.scss */
  100% {
    bottom: 720px;
  }
}


#space{
 position: relative;
 bottom: 170px;
 border:0px;
}

#space-ship{
 position: relative;
 border:0px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 bottom: 750px;
 left: 150px;
 animation-name:space01;
    animation-duration: 2.2s;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
   width: 20%;
   height: 20%;
}

.menu-a{
 padding: 0;
 border:0px;
 margin-right:  0;
 position: relative;
 right:0
}

#fred-portal{
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 border:0px;
 padding: 0;
 bottom: 780px;
 left: 500px;
 width: 10%;
   height: 10%;
} 

#owl-portal{
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 border:0px;
 padding: 0;
 bottom: 850px;
 left: 950px;
 width: 10%;
   height: 10%;
}

#portal-sun{
 position: relative;
 border:0px;
 width: 20%;
   height: 20%;
   bottom: 950px;
   left: 550px;
}
```

Para organização do conteúdo usei divs, porém ao reposicionar os elementos via css, ao utilizar o inspect do chrome e mozzila percebi que as divs estão totalmente confusar, não acompanharam seus conteudos ocupando espaços inexistente enquanto o conteudo está em um lugar totalmente diferente.
Alguém já teve algum problema similar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
        <title>Portal do Aluno</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon_conecturma.png" >
</head>
<body>
        <div id="portal_bg" >
            <img src="img/tela_ambiente-do-aluno.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            <div  id="header-menu">
            <div>
        <header>
            <img src="img/header-menu-1.png"  class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            <ul id="header-icons">
            <li>
            <a  class="menu-a" href="#">
            <img src="img/C-icon.png" id="C-icon" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a class="menu-a" href="#">
            <img src="img/ambiente-icon.png" id="ambiente-icon" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a class="menu-a" href="#">
            <img src="img/facebook-icon.png" id="fb-icon" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a class="menu-a" href="#">
            <img src="img/youtube-icon.png" id="youtube-icon" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a class="menu-a" href="#">
            <img src="img/sair-icon.png" id="sair-icon" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </header>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="owl-image">
            <img src="img/owl-portal.png" id="owl-portal">
        </div>
        <div id="space" >
            <img src="img/portal-sun.png" id="portal-sun">
            <img  id="fred-portal" src="img/fred-portal.png">
            <img src="img/space-ship.png"  id="space-ship" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Geralmente esses problemas ocorrem se você esquecer de fechar a `div`. Sua pergunta está ampla demais, para descobrirmos o que é, mas tente começar por isso que falei.

Comment: Por favor, anexe seu código à sua pergunta para podermos ajudá-lo

Comment: E como a @eliangela disse, não esqueça de clicar em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/311618/edit) e adicionar mais código e mais detalhes à sua pergunta, pois senão a mesma será fechada.

Comment: ok, não tenho o costume de usar o stack, é a segunda vez. Perdoe a falta do código previamente destacada por vcs

Comment: Tudo bem @igorsilva. Eu analisei o seu código pelo VS CODE e, aparentemente, não é problema com fechamento de tag

Comment: É provavel que o problema esteja no modo de posicionamento das imagens no CSS. Todas as imagens tem `position: relative`? Se sim, elas vão ocupar o espaço original delas e irão se mover com as informações nos atributos `right, left, top, bottom`.

Comment: Sim, todas estão com relative

Comment: Então o problema tá nisso aí. No relative, o elemento ainda ocupa o espaço dele pelo código, o CSS só desloca ele pra X ou Y coordenadas. Pelo menos é o que a **minha** experiência me conta. A "base" do elemento ainda fica dentro da DIV, mas a exibição dele pode variar.

Comment: Para corrigir deveria mudar a posição da div em html? Comecei trabalhar com front agora, ainda estou estudando, então perdão certa ignorancia em html e css

Comment: Amigo já que vc falou que está começando com fronte agora vou te dizer uma coisa, valore como por exemplo bottom: 850px; ou left: 950px; provavelmente são desnecessários! Estudo um pouco de CSS, leia sobre como construir um grid para um site, sobre floats e display, ai vc vai começar a entende melhor a estrutura do HTML. A forma como vc montou o seu layout vai ser quase impossível de deixar responsivo e só vai servir na tela do seu computador...

Answer (score 0):

Faltou você fechar uma div id="header-menu"
Veja se assim resolve o seu problema:
(Não tenho como testar aqui pois faltam CSS's que estão linkados ao seu código mas não presentes na pergunta)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Portal do Aluno</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

</head>
<body>
    <div id="portal_bg" >
        <img src="img/tela_ambiente-do-aluno.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
        <div  id="header-menu">
            <div>
                <header>
                    <img src="img/header-menu-1.png"  class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                    <ul id="header-icons">
                    <li>
                    <a  class="menu-a" href="#">
                    <img src="img/C-icon.png" id="C-icon" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                    </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a class="menu-a" href="#">
                    <img src="img/ambiente-icon.png" id="ambiente-icon" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                    </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a class="menu-a" href="#">
                    <img src="img/facebook-icon.png" id="fb-icon" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                    </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a class="menu-a" href="#">
                    <img src="img/youtube-icon.png" id="youtube-icon" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                    </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a class="menu-a" href="#">
                    <img src="img/sair-icon.png" id="sair-icon" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                    </a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </header>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="owl-image">
        <img src="img/owl-portal.png" id="owl-portal">
    </div>

    <div id="space" >
        <img src="img/portal-sun.png" id="portal-sun">
        <img  id="fred-portal" src="img/fred-portal.png">
        <img src="img/space-ship.png"  id="space-ship" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: To usando sistema de grid do bootstrap agora, tá tudo meio diferente mas tive problema similar em relação a div e seus conteúdos